# Macbook battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I have a macbook pro 2010 15 inch A1286.
My problem is that the power adapter is plugged into the MacBook but it indicates that the battery is not charging and "Power Source: Power Adapter". The battery cycle count is over 1000 and condition is "replace soon". I was wondering if this problem with my device not charging is due to the degradation of the battery. Thank you for your help and if there is any more information that I should provide to facilitate this diagnostics, please feel free to say so.

Comment: yes, the age is the problem

Comment: so the reason for my power adapter not showing a led light is because of the battery and replacing the battery will solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, yes.

Your MacBook Pro battery has a life expectancy at or around 1000 cycles.  It's not uncommon for batteries to exceed or fall short of this number; it's just an estimation of how long it can last.   You can refer to [Determine battery cycle count for Mac notebooks](https://support.apple.com/HT201585) on Apple's website for more info.

It seems you've had a good run overall and extracted most, if not all of the value out of it.  It's time to replace it.

Your options are to have the battery replaced or to only use it while connected to an AC power source. There are many 3rd party battery options available for purchase, so if you're still happy with your MBP then that's your best option. If not, then it's time to upgrade.

If you do decide to replace the battery, then I would ensure that you purchase a battery from a reputable online store dealing with Apple products.

For example, the following are some well-regarded sites:

- [Mac Sales](https://eshop.macsales.com/search/battery)
- [Simply Mac](https://simplymac.sg/search?q=battery)
- [RAM City](https://www.ramcity.com.au/upgrade/accessories/laptop-batteries/131413)
- [Macfixit](https://www.macfixit.com.au/apple-laptop-batteries)

By buying from a reputable store you'll be sure to get a battery fit for purpose, regardless of manufacturer. Being reputable means they're only going to sell something that works and they'll stand behind the product they sell, regardless of the brand.

Comment: Oops...forgot to up vote after editing!  Doh!  +1

Comment: @Allan LOL, no worries! And I really like your wording - much better than what I had. Thanks for the edit! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your battery is breaking records in life time.

Pretty sure the charger light is not showing, because your battery is total loss.

When a battery gets to old, it can not retain any charge (be charged) any more.

So your Magsafe will not show charging light.

It just needs to be replaced, and you can do it yourself, just make sure you buy the right one for your model.

[Instructions how to replace battery](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2010+Battery+Replacement/3024)